# Why does excel sometimes produce 'incorrect' error messages?

Tags: excel, compiler-errors, vba

Take the code below; I am missing an `End With` however when it is compiled the error is: `Next without For` which is incorrect.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Payments()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    '--> Format the original workbook
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            .UsedRange.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

    Next

End Sub
```

I have seen this behaviour with other errors too where the problem is not communicated properly. Why is this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is not incorrect. From the interpreter's point of view, the first problem that it encounters is that you have a `Next` inside a `With` block, which of course is an error.

Compilers and interpreters (with the possible exception of the [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) C compiler) are not good at guessing which of two possible errors is the one you "meant" to have.

Comment: + 1 Spot On :-) I had to discard my post LOL

Comment: just to be more precise, the `Next` inside the `With` block is an error, because there is no `For` inside this block?

Comment: @Jook: Precisely. The interpreter knows there's an error, and searching back up through scopes to figure out which one the user *meant* to use is a pretty pointless exercise just to produce an error message. And it might not even be right.

Comment: Yeah, just tested again myself - which is a nice excercise: first add a `for` before the `next`, debug, then add an `end with` after the next, debug, then add a `next` after the `end with`, debug.

Answer (score 4):

The error message you are getting is correct. "Next without For" is the error message because your code is attempting to terminate a `For` code block while still executing a `With` code block. `Next` and `End With` are both terminating statements, and nested blocks must be terminated in the correct order.

A more plain-English reading of the error message would be, "You are trying to terminate a `For` block of code, but you are currently in a block of code of some type other than `For` so I don't know what to do here." It so happens that you were in a `With` block, but the compiler isn't smart enough to include that information in its error message. So, the error message is correct, but it could certainly be improved.

I misunderstood the deliberate nature of the code error in the example. Here is an error-free version for reference purposes:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Payments()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    '--> Format the original workbook
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            .UsedRange.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is valid. However, this is how VB compiler/intererpter works.
With the following code, it throws

> Compile error: End With without With

```
Public Sub Payments()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    '--> Format the original workbook
    With ws
        .UsedRange.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    End With

End Sub
```

It looks like it goes last in first out (i.e. found `End With`, but the previous element isn't a `With`.